# Like Box Height Being Cut

Tags: facebook, height, facebook-likebox, cut

Why is the like box bottom being cut when I set a custom height? It just cuts the faces and its lower part isn't shown.

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Show code, please! We can't do zip without it.

Comment: What are you talking about? What language?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correction properly, this would be because you're not setting the height of the contents of the box, but rather the box itself.

```
<div height="x">
```

doesn't care about what's in the div, it makes the div only show x amount of it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and added these to my CSS

```
.fb-like span {
    height: auto !important;
}

.fb-like iframe {
    position: relative !important;
}
```